# MySQL Workbench 6.0.6.11184 too slow

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using the latest version of MySQL Workbench but every time I try to write a query the application freezes up to 10 seconds and then I can continue writing, this did not happen with version 5. Is there any way to speed up MySQL Workbench 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with wait cycles while typing might be caused by code completion. Try switching it off in the preferences and see if that solves your problem. Also, consider opening a bug report (http://bugs.mysql.com), so we can take care of that problem.

Comment: Already tried that when my ETL didn't work. I ended up buying MSSQL to MySQL for USD 50. True story.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently upgraded to version 6 from 5.247 (on Jan 29 2014). It is absolutely unusable. i write lots of stored procedures on a daily basis and it is EXTREMELY slow. I disabled the Code Completion, and no change.

I had to downgrade back to the older version. I am very disappointed because 5.247 has a huge bug where it does not always detect changes in the stored procedures when I edit them. I have to rename the stored procedure, then save it, then rename it again.

Version 6 fixed that bug, but it is so slow I almost pulled the few remaining hairs I have on my head completely out. I spoke to a friend who had the same issue, he already filed a bug report. I hope they get this fixed, it must be happening to alot of folks. Its a great database, I have less issues with MySQL than I ever did with MS Sql Server.  - Clark Vera

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Workbench isn't high on Oracle's priority list, which is sad, because there are few MySQL suites around and with TOAD for MySQL you can't do certain migrations.

You could try with TOAD and there's also the MySQL component of Netbeans (which is oracle's by the way).

I ditched MySQL Workbench after it kept crashing on a SQLServer to MySQL ETL.

Comment: Your assumption is completely wrong. MySQL Workbench releases are pushed out every couple weeks

Comment: So I get negative reputation because you think pushing minor releases is actually improving an already useless product? Well, thanks a lot. Sure my ETL will start magically working after that.

Comment: I was only refering to your assumption that MySQL Workbench is low on Oracle's priority list. As you can see from the work which is done this is plain wrong. A new major release went out just a couple weeks ago etc. No software is bug free and MySQL Workbench (Community Edition) is an Open Source product with no cost for you or anybody, so instead giving WB a bad public reputation you could file a bug report and we will fix that bug (which will also help you to get your job done).

Comment: While I agree amenadiel made an assumption, there is really zero excuse for how slow Workbench is. I've tried every tip I can find to speed it up and nothing particularly helps. Doesn't matter what machine, it's slow with large systems and it's slow with small personal projects. I've switched to Jetbrain's 0xDBE and I'm never looking back - and it's still considered beta software! I know the same people that work on MySQL itself most likely don't work on Workbench, but you'd think the entity that "owns" MySQL would make the best tool to use with it. I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

V.6.0.11834 is also too slow to use. When I checked for updates via the Help menu it tells me I have the latest. It's definitely within workbench as the queries take negligible time, yet it takes about 15 seconds to populate the 11 visible rows in the result area (multiple passes) for each of the three queries below.

I'm running on Windows 8 under Parallels on a MacBook Pro Retina.

15:06:12|select * from participants LIMIT 0, 1000|260 row(s) returned|0.000 sec / 0.000 sec

15:06:12|select * from moves where participant_xid = '...' LIMIT 0, 1000|186 row(s) returned| 0.031 sec / 0.016 sec

15:06:17|select * from sleeps where participant_xid = '...' LIMIT 0, 1000|265 row(s) returned| 0.031 sec / 0.000 sec

Off to the bug list to enter this there...

Answer (score 0):

...I guess the slowness happens because of the context help. This feature queries the server's help tables to get help information for a specific topic that MySQL Workbench derives from the current caret position. Try this: hide the context help pane (activate snippet tab or hide the right side bar). If that context help pane is not visible no help queries are sent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidFaber  In what way is "try hiding the context help" not an answer to the question "how can I make MySQL WB go faster"?

Comment: I think things like "try this" are best reserved for comments on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, workbench got disconnected couple of times and it turns out that the processes that I was running didn't terminate correctly. So I used command line to connect to my database and kill the processes manually. Some useful commands after you connect with mysql command:

- `show processlist;`
- `kill <pid>`

hope this helps.